# Convert lat long to utm NAD83 zone 20

Tags: r, latitude-longitude, rgdal, utm

I have 2 similar data sets, where I want to convert my latitude and longitude to UTM (NAD83 Zone 20N). One of my data sets has the raw data [Data set 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nt9Jc.png), and for the other one I have calculated the average position based on a given time interval [Data set 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZRTn6.png).

The second data set does have a few NAs in the mean lat and long sections, yet I would need to find a way in the code to accept the NAs and convert all the other lat/longs.

I have tried using different codes that I have found on the Internet, but they are giving me errors or won't convert lat/long to UTM.

**Code 1**

```
setwd("~/Documents/UVI/Thesis/Data/Analyses/Practice/MCP_Lsynagris")

tagdata<-read.csv("Data/allcombinedMAforSA.csv", header=T, sep=",", strip.white=T)
tagdata$detection_time_ast<-as.POSIXct(tagdata$detection_time_ast, format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",tz="UTC")

tagdata<-tagdata[order(tagdata$detection_time_ast),]

cord.dec = SpatialPoints(cbind(tagdata$long_nad83, -tagdata$lat_nad83), proj4string = CRS("+proj=longlat"))
#Transfoming coordinate to UTM using ESPG 26920 for NAD83 Zone 20N.
cord_UTM<-spTransform(cord.dec, CRS("+init=esp:26290"))
cord_UTM
```

For the first set of codes I received the following error

```
> cord_UTM<-spTransform(cord.dec, CRS("+init=esp:26290"))
Error in spTransform(cord.dec, CRS("+init=esp:26290")) : 
  error in evaluating the argument 'CRSobj' in selecting a method for function 'spTransform': Error in CRS("+init=esp:26290") : no system list, errno: 2
> cord_UTM
Error: object 'cord_UTM' not found
```

**Code 2**

```
tagdata<-read.csv("Data/allcombinedMAforSA.csv", header=T, sep=",", strip.white=T)

tagdata$detection_time_ast<-as.POSIXct(tagdata$detection_time_ast, format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",tz="UTC")

tagdata<-tagdata[order(tagdata$detection_time_ast),]

coordinates(tagdata) <- c("long_nad83", "lat_83")
proj4string(tagdata) <- CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=NAD83")  

res <- spTransform(tagdata, CRS("+proj=utm +zone=20 ellps=NAD83"))
res
as(res, "SpatialPoints")
```

Here are the following errors I received in the second code

```
Error in `[.data.frame`(object, , value) : undefined columns selected
> proj4string(tagdata) <- CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=NAD83")  
Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘proj4string<-’ for signature ‘"data.frame", "CRS"’
> 
> res <- spTransform(tagdata, CRS("+proj=utm +zone=20 ellps=NAD83"))
Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘spTransform’ for signature ‘"data.frame", "CRS"’
> res
Error: object 'res' not found

> as(res, "SpatialPoints")
Error in .class1(object) : object 'res' not found
```

Is there a better way to go about converting my lat/long to UTM NAD83 Zone 20 for either dat set? As well as, for the code to accept that there are NA's in the average lat/long columns for my second data set.

Comment: `CRS("+init=esp:26290")` should be `CRS("+init=epsg:26290")` - it stands for European Petroleum Survey Group. Try your first code again. Also there's a separate http://gis.stackexchange.com site for r/gis questions.

Comment: Also, examples are a lot clearer if you stop after the first error - there's no point listing all your code if it falls over on the first line! Try and make your problem statement as minimal as possible.

Comment: I tried doing it and it gave me a similar error again: Error in spTransform(cord.dec, CRS("+init=epsg:26290")) : 
  error in evaluating the argument 'CRSobj' in selecting a method for function 'spTransform': Error in CRS("+init=epsg:26290") : no options found in 'init' file

Comment: 26290 is not a valid epsg code. where did you get that number from? Did you mean 26920? http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/26920/

Comment: More tips: please try and supply either sample data files or paste text into your question - its impossible for us to get the information from images and we might make typing errors copying it in.

Comment: I think I had a typo on the epsg code for my NAD83. But it works now. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this code from an online source (don't have the reference handy):

```
LongLatToUTM<-function(x,y,zone){
  require(sp)
  xy <- data.frame(ID = 1:length(x), X = x, Y = y)
  coordinates(xy) <- c("X", "Y")
  proj4string(xy) <- CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84")  ## for example
  res <- spTransform(xy, CRS(paste("+proj=utm +zone=",zone," ellps=WGS84",sep='')))
  return(as.data.frame(res))
}
```

Note that this is for `WGS84`.

Comment: Thats the code I was using for my second code. Let me give it a shot again. Just double checking, my "xy" data set can be changed to my own data set variable as "tagdata" and simply changing my X and Y factors based on my column names, right?

Comment: For NAD83 Zone 20, I would just chase WGS84 to NAD83, right?

Comment: Hi @Masoud, I dont think it is working. It doesn't seem to print out the data frame from the loop results. I am also trying to see that I can then merge those results to my previous table.

Comment: Which loop you are talking about?

Comment: The code you gave me is a loop. it starts with a "{" and ends with a "}", which normally makes it a loop. Nevertheless, it won't show any results that it converted my latlong to utm.

Comment: Oh no, it's a function, not a loop. You copy/paste this exactly and run it. Then you run this on your dataframe. for instance like this: `new.coordinates <- LongLatToUTM(tagdata$long_nad83, -tagdata$lat_nad83,20)` The only change would be changing `WGS84` to `NAD83`. P.S. you can read [here](https://www.statmethods.net/management/userfunctions.html) about user defined functions.

Comment: that worked. Thanks. Now I am just trying to add the converted lat/longs to my original data. I've tried by making them into data frames and then using the merge function, but it is giving me zero observations, but the right amount of columns. Do you know how that can be done?

Comment: I found this video that used the same code as you did and merged his original data with the calculated data frame, however he did it by "ID". I wouldn't be able to do that, because my data set has over 60000 observations pertaining 5 individuals, so I would not be able to merge by ID, it would need to be by the same observation/row. [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XfdEnE99lq8)

Comment: @DonajiDuffingRomero Just use this `tagdata <- c (tagdata, new.coordinates)`